# Typescript wait until condition to push element in array

Tags: angular, typescript, wait

I need help to solve this problem: I'm pushing and removing, after a setted time, elements in array in this way:

```
...    
let elem = { title: this.title, message: this.message }
this.alerts.push(alert);
setTimeout(() => {
    this.alerts.splice(this.alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
}, this.getTimer(this.message));
...
```

getTimer returns a value based on message length. I need to push an element in the array only if array length is less then 4, otherwise I need to wait until an element is deleted and length become 3. 
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just take the first three elements of the array?

Comment: I'm pushing elements in the array. Pushing the forth element, I need to check if the array has 3 element and in this case I need to wait an element deletion before pushing it. The array can contain at maximun 3 elements at time.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to have a view into the array ... just slice the first three elements of the array when you're trying to read them